# Why is my "git rebase master" returning too much commits than "normal" after the lastest merge?

Tags: git, branch, commit, rebase

I try to understand what I am doing wrong but nothing. I am totally confused.
I know that another way to merge branches (or commits) is to use "git rebase".
I have 3 branches: master and 2 others for different features. Let's talk about master, f1 and f2.
I am working on my f1, and I need another feature, so I create f2.
when I finish with f1, master has already another changes. I want to rebase f1 on master. I did it, and I see 144 steps. I try to fix all commits and I push the changes. Now I apply my f2 commits to f1 and decide to do a pull request to master. I try to rebase f1 on master and I get 244 steps. or it is just 4 new commits on master. And I already get them on my local master.

I am so confused. Everytimes I want to use rebase, it seems I get more steps that commits really done.

I must tell that in the beginning I was just doing merges with "git merge" but I was asked to do them with "git rebase".

I try to search why I have too much steps, I followed tutorials again, but I cannot try to fix more that 200 steps again. It is boring and needs time.
Can you explain me more and help to fix this situation, please?
I do not want to fix this now and get more than 300 later.
thanks

Comment: "Another way to merge branches is to use git rebase" No, it's **not**. Might be the source of the confusion. I'd suggest rereading the base definitions before anything else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a misunderstanding of what rebase does, and I believe this is what has created this very frustrating situation.

**What might have happened**

Suppose you have the follow situation (which I believe is what you described).

```
master  o---o---o---o---o---o
                 \
feature1          A---B---C
                           \
feature2                    X---Y---Z
```

You're done with work on `feature1`, but there are some commits on master that haven't been tested with the `feature1` changes. So, to update `feature1` you do the following:

- `git checkout feature1`
- `git rebase master`

This results in the following situation:

```
master  o---o---o---o---o---o
                 \           \
feature1          \           A'---B'---C'
                   \        
feature2            A---B---C---X---Y---Z
```

Wait, what? Why are there two copies of `A-B-C`!?

That's what `rebase` does. `Rebase` makes NEW commits starting from the base given in the command (`master` in this situation).

**What probably happened next**

Now that `feature1` has been updated with the latest from `master`, you need to update `feature2`. So, you follow the same process:

- `git checkout feature2`
- `git rebase feature1`

This results in the following situation:

```
master  o---o---o---o---o---o
                             \
feature1                      A'---B'---C'
                                         \        
feature2                                  A"---B"---C"---X---Y---Z
```

Uh oh.

As you can see, after a few times through this cycle you end up in a very bad place where you have to resolve "conflicts" that are just applying the same changes over and over.

**How to fix the current mess**

Just bite the bullet and use `merge`. Seriously, this is the fastest way to deal with it. Update the feature branches from `master` with `git merge master` and then `merge` the feature branches back into master (when appropriate).

Alternatively, you can delve into the dark magic that is interactive rebase. Use the `-i` flag when running `git rebase` and you will see a list of all commits it is attempting to reapply. Remove the duplicates and carry on your merry way. I don't like this approach because it's easy to make a mistake, and it's a PIA to recover from these mistakes.

**How to avoid this going forward**

[Detailed article](https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git)

In short, you need to tell git to ignore the duplicated commits. Updating `feature1` using `rebase` was fine, the problem happened with `feature2`.

- `git checkout feature2`
- `git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@{1} feature2`

Which gets us

```
master  o---o---o---o---o---o
                             \
feature1                      A'---B'---C'
                                         \        
feature2                                  X'---Y'---Z'
```

Exactly what we wanted!

So, what is this command doing?

`git rebase --onto feature1 feature1@{1} feature2`

- `--onto feature1` - we're going move these commits onto the branch `feature1`
- `feature1@{1}` - We just `rebase`'d `feature1`, so we need to get the previous commit (IE the one before the rebase). This is the start of the commit range we're moving
- `feature2` - This is the end of the commit range we're moving

NOTE: `feature1@{1}` will work when used as part of the process described in the article, but may not be correct if other git commands are run between updating `feature1` and `feature2`. In this instance, you can substitute this for the raw commit id - obtained by reviewing the output from `git log` while on `feature2` and selecting the last commit from `feature1` ("C" in the example given here).

**Other Good Reading:**

- [Atlassian article: Merging vs Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)
- [When do you use Git rebase instead of Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: Thank you to take time to answer me. You are kind. Let me read again again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You might run into this problem if you are merging on `vscode` and when you are done with the conflicts if you press the sync button at the lower left hand of the `vscode` instead of doing `git push -u origin branch-you-are-merging-to-master`